An auxillary lemma for the punctured combinatorial nullstellensatz.
I am studying a few combinatorial analogues of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz from the book Structural Additive Theory by David J. Grynkiewicz. The proof of the Punctured Combinatorial Nullstellensatz (Theorem 22.3 from the text) uses the following auxiliary lemma (Lemma 22.2 from the text).

Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $g_1(x_1),\ldots,g_k(x_k)\in
R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be monic, uni-variate polynomials over $R$, where $k\in [1,n]$. If $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \sum_{i=1}^{k}R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\cdot g_i(x_i)$ is a non-zero polynomial in the ideal generated by the polynomials $g_1(x_1),\ldots,g_k(x_k)$ over $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $\deg_{x_i}(f)\geq \deg{(g_i)}$ for some $i\in [1,k]$.

The proof is by induction on $k$. I understand why the claim is true for when $k=1$ (base case). What I don't understand is the following part of the proof.

Let $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}v_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)g_i(x_i)$, where $v_i\in R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Moreover, we may without loss of generality assume $$ v_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \not\in \sum_{i=1}^{j-1}R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\cdot g_i(x_i)$$ for each $j\in [1,k]$ with $v_j\neq 0$, i.e, each nonzero $v_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is not in the ideal generated by $g_1,\ldots,g_{j-1}$. Indeed, if $\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}u_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)g_i(x_i)$, then we can simply redefine $v_i$ to be $v_i+u_i$ for $i\in [1,j-1]$. Doing this starting at $j=k$ and working one's way to $j=2$ then gives the desired form.

The argument is not clear to me and I am looking for a rephrasing of the said construction and/or a hint which helps me understand it.
